# Cant get a random post to display on rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

I've been trying to get a single random blog post to display for my rails blog on the home page. This is the code I used from another post on stackoverflow

```
def index
  @post = Post.offset(rand(Post.count)).first
end
```

For Views I tried everything from @post.each do |post| to <%= @post %>. and it still is not displaying one random post.

Comment: Are there any posts available? Your `@post` may be `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@post = Post.offset(rand(Post.count)).first` query would return a **single random record** from `posts` table so you cannot call `each` on it (`@post.each`) as it is not a collection.

To display that random post in your view, use

```
<%= @post.try(:field_name) %>
```

where replace `field_name` with the `field` from `posts` table that you would like to display.

For example: If you have `title` and `body` fields in `posts` table that you would like to display in `index` view, use:

```
<%= @post.try(:title) %>
<%= @post.try(:body) %>
```

using `try` so that if `@post` is `nil` i.e., if there are no records in `posts` table, you wouldn't receive any error on your page.

**UPDATE**

To access the attributes of each post from a collection `@posts` set using

`@posts = Post.all`

You would need to iterate over the collection as below:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.try(:title) %>
  <%= post.try(:body) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just one more question, so the .try will only return one title all the time? even if it was @post = Post.all

Comment: Post.all returns a collection of posts records and NOT a single record so you cannot directly access title directly on a collection. You would need to iterate over it. Read my updated answer to get a better idea.